# Extract value from string SQL

Tags: sql, select, extract

I have a column in my table that has a string that looks like `"[propertyOne]=someVal,[someNum]=20,[someBool]=true"`

How would I select the "20" out of the string? There is no guarantee of the ordering of the values in the string. I attempted to write a regex but couldn't seem to achieve the result I was looking for.

Comment: Storing this data in the database as json/xml would be the perfect solution if you need to query this information later on. I assume you are not able to fix the data.

Comment: @Helio correct I can't modify the data.

Comment: `SELECT [value] FROM STRING_SPLIT(my_column, ',') WHERE [value] LIKE '%SomeNum%'` You might want to split and extract the necessary filed.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres:

```
select substring('[propertyOne]=someVal,[someNum]=20,[someBool]=true', '[0-9]+')
```

| substring |
| --- |
| 20 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bcc305bc053a4ea66b3d98e16e72afd8)

MySQL:

```
select regexp_substr('[propertyOne]=someVal,[someNum]=20,[someBool]=true', '[0-9]+') as col
```

| col |
| --- |
| 20 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f9094cb6c438b72a10acaa61049a6b0)